# Pedersen circom/circomlibjs inconsistency?

Tags: zksnark, circom

As a unit test for a larger use case, I am checking that indeed the pedersen hash I am doing in the frontend aligns with the expected hash done through a circom circuit. I am using a simple assert in the circuit and generating a witness and am feeding both the hashed and unhashed values to the circuit, recreating the hash to make sure that it goes through.

I am running a Pedersen hash in my frontend using circomlibjs. As a unit test, I have. a circuit with a simple assert that check whether the results from my frontend line up with the pedersen hash in the circom circuit.

The circuit I am using:

```
include "../node_modules/circomlib/circuits/bitify.circom";
include "../node_modules/circomlib/circuits/pedersen.circom";

template check() {
    signal input unhashed;
    signal input hashed;
    signal output createdHash[2];

    component hasher = Pedersen(256);
    component unhashedBits = Num2Bits(256);

    unhashedBits.in <== unhashed;

    for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        hasher.in[i] <== unhashedBits.out[i];
    }

    createdHash[0] <== hasher.out[0];
    createdHash[1] <== hasher.out[1];

    hashed === createdHash[1];
}

component main = check();
```

In the frontend, I am running the following,

```
import { buildPedersenHash } from 'circomlibjs';


export function buff2hex(buff) {
    function i2hex(i) {
      return ('0' + i.toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return '0x' + Array.from(buff).map(i2hex).join('');
}


const secret = (new TextEncoder(32)).encode("Hello");

var pedersen = await buildPedersenHash();
var h = pedersen.hash(secret);

console.log(buff2hex(secret));
console.log(buff2hex(h));
```

The values that are printed are:

```
0x48656c6c6f
0x0e90d7d613ab8b5ea7f4f8bc537db6bb0fa2e5e97bbac1c1f609ef9e6a35fd8b
```

Which are consistent with the test done [here](https://github.com/iden3/circomlibjs/blob/main/test/pedersenhash.js).

So I then create an input.json file which looks as follows,

```
{
    "unhashed": "0x48656c6c6f",
    "hashed": "0x0e90d7d613ab8b5ea7f4f8bc537db6bb0fa2e5e97bbac1c1f609ef9e6a35fd8b" 
}
```

And lastly run the following script to create a witness, in the hopes that the assert will go through.

```
# Compile the circuit
circom ${CIRCUIT}.circom --r1cs --wasm --sym --c

# Generate the witness.wtns
node ${CIRCUIT}_js/generate_witness.js ${CIRCUIT}_js/${CIRCUIT}.wasm input.json ${CIRCUIT}_js/witness.wtns
```

However, I keep getting an assert error,

```
Error: Error: Assert Failed.
Error in template check_11 line: 26
```

Which describes the assert in the circuit, so I assume there is an inconsistency in the hash.

I am new to circom so any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can use logs:  https://docs.circom.io/circom-language/code-quality/debugging-operations/. to help debug exactly where/what you should see.  But another thing is that you might have to reformat it.  Play around with passing it in as a string or big number to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a discrepancy between the js implementation and the circuit. To convert the result returned by the js library, you need to use the corresponding elliptic curve. Take a look at the similar tests: https://github.com/search?q=test+pedersen+babyJub+unpackPoint&type=code

They involve some steps to convert the result using the elliptic curve:

```
const h = pedersen.hash(b);
const hP = babyJub.unpackPoint(h);

await circuit.assertOut(w, {out: [F.toObject(hP[0]), F.toObject(hP[1])] });
```